# Регулярное выражение для проверки ФИО с учетом тире

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение для проверки ФИО:

```
var regExp = /^([А-ЯA-Z]|[А-ЯA-Z][\x27а-яa-z]{1,}|[А-ЯA-Z][\x27а-яa-z]{1,}\-([А-ЯA-Z][\x27а-яa-z]{1,}|(оглы)|(кызы)))\040[А-ЯA-Z][\x27а-яa-z]{1,}(\040[А-ЯA-Z][\x27а-яa-z]{1,})?$/

if (regExp.test("Иванов-Сергеев Иван Иванович"))
    console.log("true");
else
    console.log("false");
```

Данное регулярное выражение верное, но как добавить в проверку ФИО тире? Например, для такого ФИО:

> Иванов-Сергеев Иван Иванович

У людей бывает тире в фамилии или в имени.
Как будет правильно написать такое регулярное выражение?

Comment: А бывает и апостроф, и диакритический знак встречается тоже :Р

Comment: Правильно будет не писать регулярное выражение на ФИО. Не портите жизнь ни себе, ни пользователям. Разве что на макс. длину стоит сделать ограничение, причем только как защиту от злоумышленников, которые попытаются туда подсунуть пару-тройку тысяч символов.

Comment: Вспоминается сразу известное некогда имя **[БОЧ рВФ 260602](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/БОЧ_рВФ_260602)** (Биологический Объект Человек рода Ворониных-Пархоменко, родившийся 26.06.2002 года). В общем, согласен с @Regent - не надо усложнять всем жизнь)

Comment: А ещё вспоминается Мамедов Полад Бюль-бюль оглы. :)

Comment: @Regent думаю, что ваш ответ по своей сути более верный. Он решает проблему на более высоком уровне, чем подбор нужной регулярки.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но им же отказали. А ещё _"1 мая 2017 года президент России Владимир Путин подписал указ, запрещающий регистрировать имена детей, содержащие цифры, буквенно-цифровые обозначения, символы[5]."_ :)

Comment: @Barlukov, ты ещё и про `ё` забыл.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему ты так уверен, что  ресурсом будут/могут пользоваться только исключительно русские?  А также только те, кто родился после 1 мая 2017 года ?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что в регулярке только русские и латинские символы))

Comment: @Qwertiy это не значит, что какой-нибудь необычный беларус не захочет воспользоваться)) или казах или румын. не вижу преград для них в символах)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, те же, что и для русских с `ё`. У них там что-то в духе i с двумя точками и перевёрнутого Э есть, кажется)

Comment: в чем отличие от [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/698351/186999)? Чем не подходит указанное там регулярное выражение

Comment: `javascript` не нужен, у `input` есть атрибут `pattern` где пишешь регулярку. `<input type="url" pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]">`,. Подробно тут (http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern)

Comment: не делать проверку на /^[а-яА-ЯЁё\s\-]+$/i
а чтобы всегда  были русские. не могли писать на англ в инпуте

Comment: а как сделать через js? у меня просто свой компонент Input и там этого свойства нет

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Правильно будет не писать регулярное выражение на ФИО. Не портите и не усложняйте жизнь ни себе, ни пользователям.
Разве что на максимальную длину стоит сделать ограничение. Причем только как защиту от злоумышленников, которые попытаются туда подсунуть пару-тройку тысяч символов.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, убрал регулярку

Answer (score 6):

```js
function handle() {
  var fio = document.getElementById('fio');
  fio.value = fio.value.replace(/[^А-Яа-яЁё ]/g, "");
}
var input = document.getElementById('fio');
input.onkeydown = input.onkeyup = input.onkeypress = handle;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fio" />
```

Comment: Минус `onkeyup` в том что удаляет символ после того как отпустили клавишу.

Comment: этот ответ - из вопроса, слитого с текущим как полный дубликат, поэтому он немного выбивается из контекста. не минусуйте его за это :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так

```
function isCorrectFIO(fio) {
        if (!fio) {
            return false;
    }

    var fioA = fio.split(' ');

    if (fioA.length !== 3) {
            return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (/[^-А-ЯA-Z\x27а-яa-z]/.test(fioA[i])) {
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

if (isCorrectFIO("Иванов-Сергеев Иван Иванович"))
    console.log("true");
else
    console.log("false");
```

Тут главный вопрос для чего именно?

Comment: У нас одна из дочерних фирм работает по всей стране. И там давно отвыкли от мысли, что ФИО обязательно состоит из трёх частей, разделённых запятыми. Почитайте хотя бы [раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/130361/) и [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/).

Comment: @AK не спорю, но вопрос был "как добавить тире? и как написать регулярное выражение для этого?" поэтому и ответ такой

Answer (score 1):

**Проверка полных ФИО с двойной Фамилией через тире (с учётом буквы Ё ё):**

```
/^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*([-][А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?\s[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*\s[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*$/
```

*Проверка - Иванов-Фёдоров Пётр Сидорович*

**и например для условия когда не менее 3 букв в Фамилии и Имени и Отчестве:**

```
/^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]{2,}([-][А-ЯЁ][а-яё]{2,})?\s[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]{2,}\s[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]{2,}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот верная

```
^[А-ЯЁа-яё]+(?:-[А-ЯЁа-яё]+)? [А-ЯЁа-яё]+(?: [А-ЯЁа-яё]+)*$
```

Варианты выше не пропустят НЕ с заглавной буквы ФИО, аля - Власова кристина сергеевна

Comment: Какой смысл в некропостинге?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вот такую регулярку. А вообще для ФИО их лучше не использовать

```
/^[А-Я][а-я]*([-][А-Я][а-я]*)?\s[А-Я][а-я]*\s[А-Я][а-я]*$/
```

Comment: В `{1}` смысла нет ни какого.

Comment: А вообще можно написать вот так /^([a-zA-Z '-])+$/

Comment: А русские буквы куда дели?

Comment: /^([a-zA-ZА-Яа-я '-])+$/

Comment: `ё` опять потерялось?