# Как составить регулярное выражение для проверки ФИО

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Надо проверить вот такое выражение:

```
ИВАНОВ-АВДЕЕВ-ИЛЬЧЕНКО=ИГОРЬ=АЛЕКСЕЕВИЧ
```

В ФИО могут быть только заглавные русские буквы

В ФИО может быть тире, но **не 2 и более тире подряд**

Тире может быть где угодно, и его может не быть в начале и в конце фамилии, имени или отчества.

Фамилия от имени и отчества разделена знаком =

Не надо писать, что не рекомендуется использовать регулярки для проверки.
Нужна именно регулярка!

У меня получилось вот так:

```
^(?!-)([А-ЯЁ-]{1,30})(?<!-)=([А-Я-Ё]{1,30})=([А-Я-Ё]{1,30})
(?!-) - тире не может быть в начале
([А-ЯЁ-]{1,30}) - от 1 до 30 символов от А до Я, включая Ё и -
(?<!-) - тире не может быть в конце
```

Как вставить регулярку на проверку того факта, что 2 тире не могут идти подряд?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688414/186083

Comment: а вариант не одного, а нескольких выражений не рассматриваете? это упростит и выражения, и работу с ними.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж у Вас так жестко задан формат ФИО, ничего не может быть проще (на латинице для простоты):

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+(-[A-Z]+){0,2}=[A-Z]+(-[A-Z]+){0,2}=[A-Z]+(-[A-Z]+){0,2}')
>>> p.match('BENDER-BEY=OSTAP-SULEIMAN=BERTA-MARIA')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000022B4750>
>>> p.match('BENDER-BEY=OSTAP=BERTA-MARIA')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000022B47E8>
>>> p.match('BENDER-BEY=OSTAP-SULEI-MAN-OGLU=BERTA-MARIA')
>>>
```

То, что разделено знаками `=`, можно выделить в именованные группы для фамилии, имени и отчества. В предположении, что нигде нет более двух тире. Но гораздо проще:

```
lastname, firstname, secondname = fio.split('=')
```

А потом проверить отдельно каждую часть.

Comment: @Visman 2 тире подряд - не пройдет регулярку, так же, как и тире в начале/конце части. Если дефисов внутри имени/фамилии может быть сколько угодно (*остап-сулейман-берта-мария*) надо просто заменить `{0-2}` на `*`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, сейчас только заметил, что тире у вас вне символьных классов стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ! Не могу пометить его правильным и комментарий написать.
У меня получилось вот так:

```
^[А-ЯЁ]+(-[А-ЯЁ]+)*=[А-ЯЁ]+(-[А-ЯЁ]+)*=[А-ЯЁ]+(-[А-ЯЁ]+)*$
```

Может не очень красиво, но именно то, что нужно.

[А-ЯЁ]+ - сначала идет буква 1 или более раз

(-[А-ЯЁ]+) - группа, которая начинается с - и затем может идти 1 или более букв

- (звездочка) означает, что группа может отсутствовать либо повторяться бесконечное число раз.

Спасибо за идею!

Comment: Так регистрироваться надо перед тем как вопросы задаете.

Comment: Вчера он мне написал - у Вас недостаточно репутации, чтобы оставлять комментарии. Хотя я зарегистрировался.