# Регулярное выражение в проверке данных поля input атрибутом pattern

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, input

Необходимо реализовать проверку ввода данных ФИО на уровне 3х полей **HTML input** с помощью регулярного выражения атрибутом **pаttern**.

**Требования к формату:**

1. Регистронезависимость (первая буква устанавливается заглавной    автоматически JavaScript'ом).
2. Допустима либо только латинница либо только кириллица.

*В случае кириллицы:*

3. Недопустимы символы **ь** и **ъ** в начале.
4. Недопустим символ **ъ** в конце.
5. Недопустимы сочетания символов **ьъ**, **ьь**, **ъъ** и **ъь**.

Пробовал различные вариации регуляного выражения, в частности,

`pattern="^[a-z]|^[^ьъ]?[а-я]+$/i"`,

но оно не обеспечивает всех требований и в случае правильного ввода типа "Иванов" браузер считает как неформат, хотя тестирование рег. выражения на соответствующем сайте прошло успешно.

Подскажите, как составить корректное регуляное выражение, если не затруднит то с объяснением!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688338/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9E-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример:

```html
<form action="somefile.php">
    <input type="text" name="Фамилия" placeholder="Фамилия" pattern="^((?!(.*[ъьЪЬ]{2}|[ъЪьЬ]))[А-Яа-яЁё]{2,}(-[А-Яа-яЁё]{2,})?(?<=[^ъЪ])|[A-Za-z]+)$">
</form>
```

---

```
^((?!(.*[ъьЪЬ]{2}|[ъЪьЬ]))[А-Яа-яЁё]{2,}(-[А-Яа-яЁё]{2,})?(?<=[^ъЪ])|[A-Za-z]+)$
```

Шаблон - исключаем в любом месте 2 символа мягкого и/или твердого знака
Мягкий или твердый знак вначале
Далее любое количество символов кириллицы
После необязательная группа с дефисом
Проверяем что последний символ не равен твердому знаку.

---

Либо один и более латинских символов в любом регистре